# DataSet.GetXmlSchema() do not returns nillable attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, dataset, xelement

I'm serializing `DataSet` using GetXmlSchema() and GetXml() methods (code below), but in `schema` and `xmlData` **there is no `xsi:nil` or `nillable` attributes for columns which are nullable**. When deserializing how could I know that column is nullable?

```
XElement schema = XElement.Parse(dataSet.GetXmlSchema());
XElement xmlData = XElement.Parse(dataSet.GetXml());
```

Is there any way to get those attributes in serialized xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybce7f69%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Looks like you may need to be using XMLSerializer.

Also if a non-nullable type (int for example) has a nil=true it looks like it'll throw an error. That's on the referenced page.